# How to make a Loop in R referencing a data set

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I'm confused on how to run a complicated loop. I want R to run a function (rpt) on each of the 14 turtles in the data set (starting with R3L12). Here is what the code looks like for just running the function for one turtle.

```
R3L12repodba <- rpt(odba ~ (1|date.1), grname = "date.1", data= R3L12rep, 
datatype = "Gaussian", nboot = 500, npermut = 0)

print(R3L12repodba)
```

The problem is is that the dataset will be changing each time. For the next turtle, turtle R3L1, the data = would be R3L1rep.

It could just be easier to copy and paste the above code and change it for the 13 turtles, but I wanted to see if anyone could help me with a loop.

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like the problem is caused by having a bunch of separate variables with data stored in the variable name itself. In R, those tasks are generally better solved using lists to keep related data together which allows you to easily perform actions over every element in the list. How did you create all the data objects in the first place?

Comment: All of the data was stored in a giant data set, but the function I'm using needs the individuals separated (aka why I had to make 14 mini data sets). All I did was take the giant data set and filter it to be one specific turtle. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a vector containing the names of each dataset.

```
data_names=c("R3L12rep","R3L1rep")
```

Then loop over each name:

```
for(i in seq_along(data_names)){
  foo = rpt(odba ~ (1|date.1), 
              grname = "date.1", 
              data= data_names[i], 
              datatype = "Gaussian", 
              nboot = 500, 
              npermut = 0))
  print(foo)
}
```

Comment: I did this and it didn't work. **Error in data[no_NA_vals, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
In addition: Warning message:
In rptGaussian(formula, grname, data, CI, nboot, npermut, parallel,  :
  2 rows containing missing values were removed**                                                          Maybe something is wrong with my data?

Answer (score 0):

put your datasets into a list, then iterate over that list:

```
datasets = list(R3L12rep,R3L1rep, <insert-rest-of-turtles>)
for (data in datasets) {
    R3L12repodba <- rpt(odba ~ (1|date.1), grname = "date.1", data= data, 
                        datatype = "Gaussian", nboot = 500, npermut = 0)

    print(R3L12repodba)
}
```